# Find $f(1729)$ if $n^2\int_{x}^{x+\frac 1 n} f(t)\;\text{d}t=nf(x)+0.5$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I was asked this question-

> Let $f$ be a real continuous function satisfying $f(0)=0$ and for each natural number $n$
> $$n^2\int_{x}^{x+\frac 1 n} f(t)\;\text{d}t=nf(x)+0.5$$
> Then find the value of $f(1729)$

I couldn't make much of a progress. But I tried using
$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(x)\;\text{d}x$$
so that
$$\int_{x}^{x+\frac 1 n} f(t)\;\text{d}t=F\left(x+\frac 1 n\right)-F(x)$$
and then maybe letting $n$ go to infinity such that we can think about the behaviour of
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^2\cdot \left(F\left(x+\frac 1 n\right)-F(x)\right)$$

But, soon I realised that we don't even know whether this limit exists, since we don't have any idea of whether the limit in the RHS exists, i.e., we don't know whether
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} nf(x)$$
exists. However, if this would somehow exist, we could have argued that the limit of the LHS also exists, and thus,
$$\left(F\left(x+\frac 1 n\right)-F(x)\right)=\frac {h(x)}{n^2}$$
But still, there's no progress.

Another approach that I tried was to sum up the equation from $1$ to $k$ to get
$$\sum_{n=1}^k n^2\int_{x}^{x+\frac 1 n} f(t)\;\text{d}t = \frac {k(k+1)}2 f(x) + \frac k 2$$
But how to calculate the sum on the LHS? I tried writing it as
$$\sum_{n=1}^k n^2\cdot \left(F\left(x+\frac 1 n\right)-F(x)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^k n^2\cdot F\left(x+\frac 1 n\right) - \sum_{n=1}^k n^2\cdot F(x)$$
where the second term maybe easy to calculate, but what about the first term?

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I'm not really sure about the tags- feel free to edit them.

Comment: The only way $\lim_{n\to\infty} nf(x)$ could exist is if $f(x)=0$.

Comment: The identify function on $\mathbb R$ satisfies this equation, however I don't know if it is the only one.

Comment: $f(t)=t$ satisfies this equation. If the question has a  unique answer it has to be $1729$. But I don't have a proof of  uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugging in $0$ on both sides, we obtain

$$n^2\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} f(t) dt = nf(0)+\frac{1}{2} \implies \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} f(t)dt = \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

which means $f(t)=t$ and $f(1729)=1729$

Comment: That was quite a clever and short one (+1)! Can you give a quick rigorous proof of $\int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} f(t)dt = \frac{1}{2n^2} \implies f(x)=x$? If that proof is not that hard, I think I should accept this one.

Comment: How does that mean $f(t) = t$ exactly?

Comment: @VIVID this directly shows $f(t) = t$ on the interval $0$ to $1$ only. By the original equation and the continuity of the antiderivative, you can slide the $x$ to show that the equality holds on intervals $[0,x+1]$ for all $x$, inductively if you'd like to look at integer values of $x$ only

Comment: @Sayan you can use induction to show the equality holds on intervals $[0,k+1]$. If you get stuck I can write it up.

Comment: @NinadMunshi You don't need to write the proof of the sliding part- I get that. But, give me the proof of how $f(t)=t$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Sayan Barebones, what we start with is that $\int_0^a f(t)\:dt = \frac{1}{2}a^2$ for a countably infinite subset of points. Take any number $x\in(0,1)$ and pick the closest $\frac{1}{n}$ below it. Then keep adding successive intervals of the form $ \int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n_k}}f(t)\:dt$ where $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n_k}\to x$ from below. Such a sequence will always exist because of the density of the rationals in the reals. The integral will equal $\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2n^2}$ and we are free to draw our conclusion for all real $a$ in the first expression.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let
\begin{equation}
F(x)= \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t.
\end{equation}
We may rewrite the equation as
\begin{equation}
n^2\left(F\left(x+\frac1n\right)- F(x)\right)= nf(x)+ 0.5.
\end{equation}
Since the left-hand side is continuously differentiable, so is the right hand. As a result, we deduce that $f$ is smooth, thus so is $F$. Now, by Taylor expansion we have
\begin{equation}
F\left(x+\frac1n\right)= F(x)+ \frac1n F'(x)+ \frac{1}{2n^2}F''(x)+ O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right),
\end{equation}
i.e.,
\begin{equation}
0.5= n^2\left(F\left(x+\frac1n\right)- F(x)\right)-nf(x)= \frac12 F''(x)+ n^2 O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right).
\end{equation}
Taking $n\to\infty$ we get
\begin{equation}
F''(x)=1,
\end{equation}
or equivalently, $f'(x)=1$, for all $x$. This, together with the initial condition $f(0)=0$ implies that
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x.
\end{equation}
As a result, $f(1729)= 1729$.

Comment: I think your little $o$ should be big $O$. (+1)

Comment: I always confuse the two. Thanks.

Comment: That was a nice solution (+1). Thanks!

Comment: By the way, instead of `\begin{equation} stuff \end{equation}` everytime, you can use `$$stuff$$` to go easy.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the given condition can be written as
$$\frac{F(x+1/n) - F(x)}{1/n} = f(x) + \frac{1}{2n}$$
Now differentiate both sides to get
$$\frac{f(x+1/n) - f(x)}{(\color{red}{x+}1/n) \color{red}{-x} } = f'(x)$$
by mean value theorem, there exists $\xi_{n,x} \in (x, x+1/n)$ such that
$$f'(\xi_{n,x}) = f'(x)$$
Hence, by Rolle's theorem, there exists $\eta_{n,x} \in (\xi_{n,x}, x)$ such that
$$f''(\eta_{n,x}) = 0$$
Since $\xi_{n,x}$ squeezes $\eta_{n,x}$ to $x$ as $n\to\infty$, we have $\eta_{n,x} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} x$. It follows that $$0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}f''(\eta_{n,x}) = f''(x)$$
for all $x$. Hence, $f(x)$ is a linear function.

Now, let $f(x) = ax + b$ and finish it.

Comment: That was a nice solution (+1). Thanks!